# What does * means in R?

Tags: r, boolean

For instance:

```
> TRUE * 0.5
   0.5
> FALSE * 0.5
   0
```

I don't know if the secret here is the * character itself or the way R encodes logical statements, but I can't understand why the results.

Comment: `*` is multiplication in this context; the expression is coercing the logicals `TRUE` and `FALSE` to `1` and `0`, respectively.

Comment: From `help("*")`, *These unary and binary operators perform arithmetic on numeric or complex vectors (or objects which can be coerced to them).*

Comment: what results did you expect

Answer (score 3):

R has a fairly loose type system and rather freely does coercion, hopefully when it is sensible. When coerced to numeric by `*`, logical values become 0 (FALSE)  and 1 (TRUE), your expression gets evaluated with the usual mathematical convention of all values times 0 equal 0, and all values times 1 equal the value. The one exception to that rule in the numeric domain is `Inf * 0` returns `NaN`. Character values have no "destination"-type when composed with "*", so `"1"*TRUE` throws an error.